# Gitlab only allowing cloning of with registered with LDAP, can't unhook

Tags: git, gitlab, ldap

I have a Gitlab instance (set up by a previous team before we took over) that is only allowing users to clone repos when they are also in authenticated with LDAP and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get gitlab to allow cloning repos by users that aren't in LDAP.

Standalone (e.g. non-LDAP) users can log in to the UI, but there seems to be something in the configuration that is preventing such users from performing a "git clone" - it always errors out as being unauthenticated. The only way the repos can be cloned is if they exist in LDAP and their username and password is the same in both LDAP and gitlab and I'm trying to undo this but can't figure out how.

Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is allow this repo to be cloned unauthenticated. NOTE: I have set the repo to public and added the users in after LDAP was disabled, still no go.

This is what the gitlab.rb looks like on it - this shows that everything related to LDAP and even omniauth is disabled. In the 3rd image, it shows how the authentication is failing.

[image]

Here's what it looks like on the UI:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In general, it's best to supply the text instead of images of text, because it's often difficult to see the information in the images, which may mean your question won't get answered. You can still hide your sensitive information with things like `gitlab.example.com` or `my-token`, etc.

Do you get the same result using an SSH key or personal access token to clone from the remote?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 

I can never seem to be able to authenticate with a personal access token either. Could it be that there is some kind of authentication that is occurring with gitlab in just establishing the connection at all - that is, before the client can even get authorized for the repo?